# As "private" is the default scope in C# - should the word "private" be removed from signatures for cleaner code?

Tags: c#, .net, programming-languages, coderush

I've heard various programmers suggest not including the word "private" in declarations, method signatures, etc. as private is the default scope when not specified.  It can make for cleaner code but I'm interested in what the opinions are on whether you use the "private" scope on your variables, methods, etc.  Tools like CodeRush that generate code for you include the word "private" so I'm curious if this is good or bad or just a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cleaner code is more *explicit* as to the designer's intentions. Using `private` demonstrates a deliberate choice, not open to debate. Falling to the default opens up the questions: was this on purpose, or he simply forgot to include a modifier?

Comment: Except that private is the default (except for non-nested classes).  So the best thing the designer can do, to make the code more secure and easier to understand, is keep the public surface as small as possible.  Making something private doesn't require a deliberate decision.  Making something non-private does.

Comment: @Kyralessa: I mentioned it's the default, and my argument is that, at least in principle, _everything_ that you do should be _deliberate_, not just marking something `public`.

Comment: You're assuming that omitting the modifier could only be accidental.

Comment: No, I'm assuming that a third party (or even you six months from now) wouldn't necessarily know whether it was accidental or not.

Comment: And yet, it doesn't matter if it *was* accidental, because omitting it just made it as constrained as it could be.  Nothing bad comes of that.

Comment: @Kyralessa: yes you're right, nothing bad comes out of that...

Comment: @Kyralessa, But if you omit `public`, how do you know it was intentionally meant as `private` when you just forgot to write `public`? If you clearly write `private`, there is no doubt wether you forgot to write `public` or not.

Again this is important when someone else is fixing bugs in your code. You may not be around or even not working there anymore.

Comment: @MaxKielland:  Simple: If you forgot to write public, and your code works, then the method doesn't need to be public.  Perhaps it doesn't need to exist at all!  (If you wrote the method and didn't bother to test it, you have bigger problems than whether or not to write a default keyword.)

Answer (score 9):

Remove the private and Ask your fellow developers whether they are confused or not

Personally i feel, including private make your code more readable. I would give more importance to **"Readability"** than **"being cleaner"**

Comment: More _readable_ code _is_ _cleaner_. Cleaner is not (necessarily) shorter!

Answer (score 3):

In a codebase where stuff being public is an information leak (e.g. it will no longer get obfuscated), you want `public` to stick out. Removing `private` also has the same 'tide going out' effect on `protected` and other unnecessarily elevated visibility.

Ideally one'd use a StyleCop rule or similar to make the code actually be consistent (though that, as with all code rules should actually be agreed among the devs before someone comes to a conclusion about it).

(BTW Your contention in the premise re CodeRush's support for omitting it is incorrect - the options allow you to set method visibility etc. to be either `private` (OOTB) or 'default' (do not specify anything)).

Comment: Ruben - can you point me to where I can make "private" not appear in DevExpress options for CodeRush?

Comment: DevExpress\Options - Editor\Code Style\Scope - Methods: Select "Default"

Comment: @RoryBecker thanks for stepping in. While we're here, I only figured out it existed because I was bloody minded and was on my 3rd lap of every options menu in there. The problem is that `Default` means little. I dont know the solution, but maybe it should say `Default (no keyword emitted)` or something? (Yes I know its more than likely technically the correct term wrt the lang standard)

Answer (score 0):

It is up to compiler how to interpret methods or other class members without private, protected or public. It can be changed in nex version. So don't do it.

Comment: That would be a _breaking_ change...

Comment: Actually, in VB6 procedures are public by default. That changed in VB.Net. Yep, breaking change. Anyone who didn't declare their method scope had a lot of work to do when migrating VB6 code to VB.Net.